# Java getter() and setter()

Tags: java, class, get, set

can someone please tell me why I cannot use the Set properly? I managed with the Get to load the Name, Surname etc.. in the text boxes but the Set is not letting me read from the text boxes and save them. Thanks

```java
 custnameTF.setText(bookingfile.getCustomer().getPersonName());
 custsurnameTF.setText(bookingfile.getCustomer().getPersonSurname());
```

```java
customerbooking.setCustomer(.setPersonName(custnameTF.getText));
```

```java
public class Booking implements Serializable{

    private String flighttime;
    private String flightlocation;
    private String flightfee;
    private boolean car;
    private boolean insurance;
    private Customer customer;
```

I'm trying to connect 2 classes together without an extend. I want to load and save on the Customer class through the Booking Class. Thanks

Comment: (.setPersonName(custnameTF.getText));
It won't compile. Please correct your question and provide more details as it's almost impossible to guess.

Answer (score 3):

First in hand, that's not the correct syntax to set.

Since that `setCustomer` accepts only `Customer` object, you need to create a `Customer` object and then set it to `bookingCustomer`.

```
Customer customer= new Customer();
customer.setPersonName(custnameTF.getText); // look at the correct syntax.
//set remaining properties to customer objects from text fields
// ..
//then
customerbooking.setCustomer(customer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setters don't return anything in general, which is why you can't call another set method with the return value of another set method (returns `void`) as the argument.